# R ID column matching row number

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (much larger with my "real" data):

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7), value = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
```

Which I then convert to a list:

```
list = split(df$value, df$id)
```

I now want to efficiently access values in the list by their id. Obviously, I could use

```
list[["6"]]
```

to get "E". Apparently, with increasing ID numbers it takes more time to access the values. Imagine a much larger list, accessing every value from 10001-20000 takes longer than accessing 1-10000.

How can I access the values faster? My idea was that I match the row ID with the ID in the list, so that `list[["6"]] == list[[6]]`, but how can I do that? Are there better options?

Edit: More information in regards of context. I use a function similar to this one:

```
test_function = function(a, b) {
  a = unique(list[[a]])
  b = unique(list[[b]])
  return (length(intersect(a, b)))
}
```

Using apply on a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      a     b
1    36    38
2    38    39
3    39    36
4    95    96
5    96    95
6   190   191
7   191   192
8   192   190
9   193   194
10  194   196
```

So, for every row in the dataframe, I want to calculate the length of the intersection between the value lists of both IDs.

Edit2: Thank you for all of your answers. I have tested all of the suggested approaches and found out that for my specific purpose, digEmAll's answer was the fastest way:

```
myEnv <- list2env(list)
get("10000",envir=myEnv)
```

Comment: To get "E" wouldn't you do `list[['6']]` or `list[[4]]`?

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing!

Comment: I'd consider looking into an `lapply` and `sapply` call as these run a lot faster. It also seems like this has to do with search optimization possibly.

Comment: If you are accessing many elements in the list, why are you using double brackets? Is this a part of a for loop?

Comment: I have added more information on context

Comment: As far a speed goes. How does indexing through the list compare with subsetting the data frame before hand? It seems like you have what you need working, but it's not efficient.

Comment: You can try to convert the list to an environment using `myEnv <- list2env(list)`, then access to elements using `get("10000",envir=myEnv)`...

Comment: I am a little confused by the `unique` and then needing to intersect them. You would be dropping values and changing row intersections? Also why is it in list and not just subseting a data frame to a new one.

Example. `library(dplyr)

df_result <- df %>%
  select(id, value)`

Comment: From your `test_function` and the sample "data.frame" that it'll be applied, it seems that you're calculating `unique` of some "list" elements more than once? You could save some calls by storing the `lapply(mylist, unique)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hash` library instead, it should be faster than a named list:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:1000000)
df$val <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
mylist <- split(df$val, df$id)

library(hash)
myhash <- hash(mylist)
myhash[["2"]]
[1] "B"
```

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  myhash[["1000000"]],
  mylist[["1000000"]]
)
Unit: microseconds
                expr       min        lq        mean     median        uq      max neval
  myhash[["1000000"]]    25.466    33.828    72.85514   103.5735   107.565   133.03   100
 mylist[["1000000"]] 10765.207 10957.911 11076.01143 11044.0010 11120.398 12145.30   100
```

One drawback would be a loss of compatability, but for this purpose it should work well

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all of your answers. I have tested all of the suggested approaches and found out that for my specific purpose, **digEmAll**'s answer was the fastest way:

```
myEnv <- list2env(list)
get("10000",envir=myEnv)
```